# read.fwf does not read all lines in a fixed width files

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to extract data from a fixed-width file using read.fwf command. But unfortunately, this code does not read all lines. It removes few lines from the last and shows a warning. The file has  5,13,366 lines but reads only 4,90,000 lines. How can I read all the lines? Any help will be appreciated.

```
library(readr)
L4 <- read.fwf("http://www.mospi.gov.in/sites/default/files/NSS75252E/R75252L04.TXT",
           c(3,
             5,
             2,
             3,
             1,
             1,
             3,
             2,
             2,
             2,
             1,
             1,
             4,
             1,
             1,
             2,
             2,
             3,
             2,
             1,
             1,
             3,
             1,
             2,
             2,
             2,
             2,
             1,
             1,
             1,
             1,
             1,
             1,
             1,
             64,
             3,
             3,
             10
             ), 
           skip=0, 
           colClasses = "character", # To convert into character
           col.names=c("a1",
                       "a2",
                       "a3",
                       "a4",
                       "a5",
                       "a6",
                       "a7",
                       "a8",
                       "a9",
                       "a10",
                       "a11",
                       "a12",
                       "a13",
                       "a14",
                       "a15",
                       "a16", # Upto now, from level 1
                       "d1",
                       "d2",
                       "d3",
                       "d4",
                       "d5",
                       "d6",
                       "d7",
                       "d8",
                       "d9",
                       "d10",
                       "d11",
                       "d12",
                       "d13",
                       "d14",
                       "d15",
                       "d16",
                       "d17",
                       "d18",
                       "d19",
                       "d20",
                       "d21",
                       "d22"
                         ),                 
           strip.white=TRUE)
```

View(L4)

Answer (score 2):

I first downloaded the file and then your code works for me. I didn't do `library(readr)` because you don't seem to be using anything from that package so why include it?

The warning:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(file, n = thisblock) :
  incomplete final line found on 'R75252L04.TXT'
```

is because there's no final end-of-line marker after the last line of the file. It gets read in ok nevertheless:

```
> L4[513366,]
        a1    a2 a3  a4 a5 a6  a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12  a13 a14 a15 a16 d1  d2 d3
513366 005 17927 75 252  1  2 362 31 31  03   4   1 3613   1   4  02 04 000 04
       d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d14 d15 d16 d17 d18 d19 d20 d21
513366  7  2 62  2 01 01               2   2   2       2           2   4
           d22
513366 1004499
```

In total I read all the lines:

```
> dim(L4)
[1] 513366     38
```

Try using `download.file` to get the file and read from that instead of from a URL. Although it works for me when I try and read from the `http` URL. Are you checking the number of lines read using `dim` like me or is that just what `View` is showing you?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply. I used `dim(L4)` which also displayed 4,90,000 lines. But using `download.file` to get the file and read from that downloaded file has helped me t0 read all lines. Though this still shows a warning msg but it works perfectly. Than you.